# How to incremental generate makefile with cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, generate

In a big project include many module or apps ,i want to add a small module or app into the project.but after modifying the cmake,i have to remove the cmake cache in build DIR and regenerate all makefile and rebuild all.That is very wasting time.how to keep most independent makefile and files in build process as last . just generate dependent file and build dependent file also.

Comment: `i have to remove the cmake cache in build DIR and regenerate all makefile and rebuild all` What's the reason for that? What's wrong with just `make`?

Comment: Well you don't have to remove the cache file.  You just update the CMakeList.txt file as needed.  Then if you run `make` it will update any Makefiles as needed and continue with the build, or you could run `make rebuild_cache` to just update the Makefiles.